# How to learn the order of content by machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-science

Data at hand: 1000 questionnaires with a finite database of questions, say 100 questions about name, gender, income etc. Each questionnaire contains 10 to 30 questions from this question database. The wording of a certain question remains identical across different questionnaires. The 100 questions have their unique label (Q1 to Q100) in the database.

Task: creating a new questionnaire. Assuming I know which questions (say 20 questions including Q1, Q5, Q10, Q22 etc) I need to ask on the new questionnaire, I need to know what order should I place these questions.

Machine learning question: how do I learn the patterns from the existing data to help myself order the 20 questions on my new questionnaire?

Answer (score 0):

A simple but inaccurate solution would count the order of each question label on the existing data. Say Q1 appeared 300 times on the existing data and 70% of time it is the first question on the questionnaire, so I predict Q1 would have order = 1 on any new questionnaire.

Alternatively, I can compute the average order of each question on the existing data. Say Q1 has a mean order of 2.53 and Q10 has a mean order of 1.33. Then when I create a new questionnaire that contains both Q1 and Q10, Q1 will be placed after Q10.

The above methods fail to capture the relationship between the questions. For instance, maybe Q5 always appears after Q6. I hope the algorithm can capture hidden patterns like this.